# CMIS java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/SessionFactory

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, cmis, opencmis

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/SessionFactory
```

I keep on getting this error when I deploy an instance of CMIS. I know that there are other questions on here with the same error message but all those questions use Alfresco. My code **does not** use Alfresco, I am using the CMIS libraries natively. When I run my CMIS code on a local development instance, it works just fine, no errors. When I deploy it to a production server, it generates the error. My local web server is Liberty and the production server is WAS.

I have already verified that my ECM instance is working just fine and so is the CMIS gateway. I am able to make changes with CMIS Workbench just fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction to try and debug this?

Comment: How are you building your application? My first guess is that you've forgotten to copy the Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS jars into your deployment

Comment: @Gagravarr I agree, it's definitely pointing towards that. Unfortunately, I do not have rights over the WAS production instance so I am not able to determine this. So I am posting this in an effort to develop alternative ideas or reasons why this could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Gagravarr was referring to was putting the jar files into your application EAR file you are deploying to WAS.